DB2 TRIGGER "FOR EACH STATEMENT", with "AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT" gives SQL code -104, SQL state 42601
IBM DB2 on Cloud, version 11.5.9.0
Trying to create a trigger on a table (object names are made up, for simplification):
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON MY_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS NEW_STUFF
FOR EACH STATEMENT
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE P_N IN (SELECT DISTINCT P_N FROM NEW_STUFF);
    INSERT INTO TABLE_A SELECT * FROM VIEW_B WHERE P_N IN (SELECT DISTINCT P_N FROM NEW_STUFF);
END;

The view VIEW_B does have TABLE_A as a reference in its definition.
I am getting this error:
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "OR INSERT" was found following "".  
Expected tokens may include:  "".. 
SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601

If I create the same trigger with only AFTER UPDATE ON MY_TABLE or with only AFTER INSERT ON MY_TABLE it works fine.  It fails when I specify both AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT.
If I try BEGIN instead of BEGIN ATOMIC I get a different error:
SQL Error [42898]: The definition of trigger "MY_SCHEMA.MY_TRIGGER" includes an 
invalid use of correlation name or transition table name "NEW_STUFF".
Reason code="4".. SQLCODE=-696, SQLSTATE=42898

I studied the documentation and the few examples I could find.  If anyone knows why the combination of UPDATE or INSERT is causing it to fail, I'd appreciate any help.

According to the docs,  if multiple events are specified (and you specify two, update or insert), then the triggered action has to be a compiled statement (i.e. cannot be "Begin atomic").  This is the reason you get the SQL0104N for the first case.
Next, for the second case,  when you have a compiled-statement for the triggered action, then OLD TABLE name and NEW TABLE name are not allowed in a trigger if the trigger is defined using a compound SQL (compiled) statement.   (this is the reason you get the reason code 4 for SQL0696N).
Consider having separate triggers instead of trying to combine both into a single trigger, or choose a different design that complies with the restrictions.

Thanks; I went through the documentation for this several times and did not catch the competing constraints you point out.  I'm going to go with separate triggers.
